# NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder with correct dependencies on Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, logback, slf4j, noclassdeffounderror

We are attempting to upgrade our logging.  Using a gradle file we are updating these packages from :

```
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3"
```

to

```
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.5"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5"
```

However, when doing this update we get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
```

We are using spring-boot, but have excluded it's logging packages which worked on the previous versions of the logging packages seen above.  This is done via :

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

We believe to be using the correct updated dependencies for these new versions shown.  We are unsure what is causing the issue as we followed other recommendations without any luck.  If anyone can help, it be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why the exclusion? As you are now again including the same dependencies as Spring Boot does, so I don't really get the exclusion in the first place. So apparently something else is still relying on this. You are stating you are using SPring Boot but fail to mention which version you are using.

Comment: We're using Spring-boot version 2.7.5.

Comment: That doesn't support SLF4J 2.x afaik and it might even be one of the classes that is checked for logging setup. Please add the full stacktrace to see where it is coming from in the first place.

Comment: Another thing is that logback version 1.4.5 seems to use slf4j 2.0.4 as a dependency so there might be some discrepancy there as well.

Comment: Ok, so I took your suggestion of using the included Spring-boot logging.  I removed the logback/slf4j packages and removed the exclusion we had added.  This appears to be working.   Initially this was set this way when we got the project.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Assuming you are using the dependency management from Spring Boot you can override the versions you want to use by specifying `ext[`slf4j.version`] = 1.7.36` (and then use the version you like). The same applies to logback (and all other dependencies, which should be in there without a `version` property.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748464/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-with-slf4j-and-logback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StaticLoggerBinder is not present in version `org.slf4j-2.0.5.`
From what I see you can find that dependency for StaticLoggerBinder  here

```
group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.19.0'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl

I also checked and the StaticLoggerBinder is present even in the latest version which is `2.19.0`

Also, I checked the old version you had of `slf4j-api 1.7.6.`
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6

That dependency also does not have StaticLoggerBinder either, but it is present in the dependency of `log4j-slf4j-impl` which I provided above.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!, You are correct slf4j seems to be missing this.  I solved this using the suggestion above and just using the Spring-boot logging.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you able to check what classes are present in a library?

Comment: You can check that in your IDE under external libraries and there you can expand your dependencies and see their packages/folders like org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder. Or you can simply download the jar, unzip it as any other zipped file and simply browse through the folders. It is the same, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the reason is that logback-classic remove org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder from v1.3.0, and spring-boot 2.x only support for logback to v1.2.x(currently is 1.2.12).

Here is the related issues:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34708
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12649